# How to know ionic installed or not

Tags: ionic-framework

i am bit confused Please help me.Based on this logs ionic installed or not?`

---

```
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/dep-graph/-/dep-graph-1.1.0.tgz

npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/init-package-json/-/init-packag
e-json-1.9.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/glob/-/glob-4.0.6.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/d8/-/d8-0.4.4.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-app-hello-world/-/cordo
va-app-hello-world-3.9.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/rc/-/rc-0.5.2.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/npmconf/-/npmconf-0.1.16.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/valid-identifier/-/valid-identi
fier-0.0.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm WARN engine cordova-js@4.0.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"
4.1.2","npm":"2.14.4"})
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":
"4.1.2","npm":"2.14.4"})
npm WARN installMany normalize-package-data was bundled with npm@1.3.4, but bund
led package wasn't found in unpacked tree
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {
"node":"4.1.2","npm":"2.14.4"})
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/domain-browser/-/domain-browser
-1.1.4.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/htmlescape/-/htmlescape-1.1.0.t
gz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/readable-stream/-/readable-stre
am-1.1.13.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/http-browserify/-/http-browseri
fy-1.7.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/resolve/-/resolve-1.1.6.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/https-browserify/-/https-browse
rify-0.0.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/insert-module-globals/-/insert-
module-globals-6.6.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/shell-quote/-/shell-quote-0.0.1
.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/xtend/-/xtend-4.0.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/os-browserify/-/os-browserify-0
.1.2.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/through2/-/through2-1.1.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/shasum/-/shasum-1.0.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/shallow-copy/-/shallow-copy-0.0
.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/punycode/-/punycode-1.3.2.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/vm-browserify/-/vm-browserify-0
.0.4.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/subarg/-/subarg-1.0.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/url/-/url-0.10.3.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/JSONStream/-/JSONStream-1.0.6.t
gz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/labeled-stream-splicer/-/labele
d-stream-splicer-1.0.2.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/syntax-error/-/syntax-error-1.1
.4.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/parents/-/parents-1.0.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/tty-browserify/-/tty-browserify
-0.0.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/util/-/util-0.10.3.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/querystring-es3/-/querystring-e
s3-0.2.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/path-browserify/-/path-browseri
fy-0.0.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/timers-browserify/-/timers-brow
serify-1.4.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/read-only-stream/-/read-only-st
ream-1.1.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/module-deps/-/module-deps-3.9.1
.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/process/-/process-0.11.2.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-browserify/-/stream-brow
serify-1.0.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/through2/-/through2-1.1.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/punycode/-/punycode-1.3.2.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/subarg/-/subarg-1.0.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/vm-browserify/-/vm-browserify-0
.0.4.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/querystring-es3/-/querystring-e
s3-0.2.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/module-deps/-/module-deps-3.9.1
.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/timers-browserify/-/timers-brow
serify-1.4.1.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/process/-/process-0.11.2.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/stream-browserify/-/stream-brow
serify-1.0.0.tgz
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 103.2
45.222.162:443
global@4.3.0 node_modules\global
├── process@0.5.2
└── min-document@2.17.0 (dom-walk@0.1.1)

ionic@1.6.5 node_modules\ionic
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── proxy-middleware@0.7.0
├── connect-livereload@0.5.2
├── progress@1.1.7
├── open@0.0.5
├── colors@0.6.2
├── q@1.0.1
├── async@0.9.2
├── crc@3.2.1
├── ncp@0.4.2
├── semver@4.3.6
├── shelljs@0.2.6
├── cross-spawn@0.2.3 (lru-cache@2.7.0)
├── cli-table@0.3.1 (colors@1.0.3)
├── form-data@0.1.4 (mime@1.2.11, combined-stream@0.0.7)
├── npm@2.1.3
├── event-stream@3.0.20 (pause-stream@0.0.11, stream-combiner@0.0.4, from@0.1.3,
 duplexer@0.1.1, split@0.2.10, through@2.3.8, map-stream@0.0.6)
├── xml2js@0.4.4 (sax@0.6.1, xmlbuilder@3.1.0)
├── opbeat-ionic@1.1.3 (console-log-level@1.1.2, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, stac
kman@0.2.3, after-all@2.0.2)
├── tiny-lr-fork@0.0.5 (debug@0.7.4, qs@0.5.6, faye-websocket@0.4.4, noptify@0.0
.3)
├── finalhandler@0.2.0 (escape-html@1.0.1, debug@2.0.0)
├── connect@3.1.1 (utils-merge@1.0.0, parseurl@1.3.0, finalhandler@0.1.0, debug@
1.0.4)
├── optimist@0.6.0 (wordwrap@0.0.3, minimist@0.0.10)
├── cheerio@0.19.0 (entities@1.1.1, dom-serializer@0.1.0, css-select@1.0.0, loda
sh@3.10.1, htmlparser2@3.8.3)
├── vinyl-fs@0.3.7 (graceful-fs@3.0.8, lodash@2.4.2, strip-bom@1.0.0, through2@0
.6.5, glob-stream@3.1.18, vinyl@0.4.6, glob-watcher@0.0.6, mkdirp@0.5.1)
├── request@2.51.0 (forever-agent@0.5.2, aws-sign2@0.5.0, caseless@0.8.0, tunnel
-agent@0.4.1, oauth-sign@0.5.0, stringstream@0.0.4, json-stringify-safe@5.0.1, m
ime-types@1.0.2, qs@2.3.3, node-uuid@1.4.3, tough-cookie@2.0.0, hawk@1.1.1, comb
ined-stream@0.0.7, bl@0.9.4, form-data@0.2.0, http-signature@0.10.1)
├── serve-static@1.7.1 (escape-html@1.0.1, utils-merge@1.0.0, parseurl@1.3.0, se
nd@0.10.1)
├── unzip@0.1.9 (setimmediate@1.0.2, readable-stream@1.0.33, match-stream@0.0.2,
 pullstream@0.4.1, binary@0.3.0, fstream@0.1.31)
├── gulp@3.8.8 (pretty-hrtime@0.2.2, interpret@0.3.10, deprecated@0.0.1, archy@0
.0.2, minimist@1.2.0, semver@3.0.1, chalk@0.5.1, tildify@1.1.1, orchestrator@0.3
.7, gulp-util@3.0.6, liftoff@0.12.1)
├── prompt@0.2.12 (revalidator@0.1.8, pkginfo@0.3.0, read@1.0.7, winston@0.6.2,
utile@0.2.1)
└── ionic-app-lib@0.3.9 (archiver@0.5.2, vinyl-fs@1.0.0, ionic-cordova-lib@5.1.7
)
```

`

in cmd line i am given npm it showing:**npm@2.14.4 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm**
and **cordova -v** :it showing **:5.0.0**.i am given ionic it showing :**'ionic' is not recognized as an operable program or batch file.**How to Solve these.

Thanks

Comment: ionic has been installed in your system, but your `Environment Variable` is not set to the `node_modules` folder

Comment: i am defined all Environment Variable now.But it showing blank screen cursor blinking more then 15min.How to slove these

Comment: Add C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ in your path.

Comment: Yes path added but it now showing anything cursor blinking only.

Comment: In Command prompt it not showing any information  cursor blinking only.

Comment: type `ionic start myApp tabs` it will start up ready-made app templates

Answer (score 4):

Type **ionic --version** to check version of ionic its return like that 
1.7.7

its means install ionic in your system.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ionic info as below

C:>ionic info

Your system information:

cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 8.1
Node Version: v4.6.0
Xcode version: Not installed

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try below command:
ionic info

You will get the following information:

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.8
Node Version: v7.9.0
Xcode version: Not installed